# Scripting to change Folder permissions en masse

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, permissions, active-directory

I've recently inherited a bit of a mess and I'm trying to script the solution...unfortunately I'm terrible at scripting.
Is there a way to create a script that will:

1. Find all folders in a directory
2. Identify them by name
3. Tie them to the correct user (the folder names are the same as AD username)
4. Set user permissions (Full control for the matched user - No permissions for other domain users)

I've been trying to work with something like this...but my understanding of how the variables would work is sub-par here.

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\MyFolder"
$Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("$username","FullControl","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "C:\MyFolder" $Acl
```

If anyone would be willing to lend me a hand it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is literally what you want to do? http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-manage-file-system-acl,2-837.html

Comment: That's literally exactly what i was trying to do - Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try leveraging the NTFS module.

File System Security PowerShell Module 4.2.3

Allows a much easier management of permissions on files and folders using PowerShell

> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85

```
#Get permissions from all files or folders in the current folder 
dir | Get-NTFSAccess 

#to read and also remove only the explicitly assigned ones 
dir | Get-NTFSAccess -ExcludeInherited | Remove-NTFSAccess 


#to backup permissions just pipe what Get-NTFSAccess returns to Export-Csv 
dir | Get-NTFSAccess -ExcludeInherited | Export-Csv permissions.csv 

#to retore the permissions pipe the imported data to Get-NTFSAccess 
#As the imported data also contains the path you do not need to specify the item 
Import-Csv .\permissions.csv | Get-NTFSAccess
```

> https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity/4.2.3